# How to get Fitnesse test name

Tags: fitnesse

Is there an API to get the name of the current test in fitnesse.NET code? 
My fixture class inherits fitlibrary.SequenceFixture.

Answer (score 2):

You can use variable ${PAGE_NAME} . On Test Page the name of the page will be here. SetUp/TearDown sub pages will use the parent page name, e.g. you can use this define on the SetUp:

```
!define myVariable {prefix_${PAGE_NAME}_suffix}
```

Then the actual test name will be used in the you variable.

Also you can create "void Init(string testName)" function and pass this variable in the SetUp.

[See here](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.QuickReferenceGuide) for details.

Answer (score 0):

There is no formal way, however you could write a method (or property) in your fixture like:

```
public string FixtureIsOfType()
{
    return this.GetType();
}
```

and then if it is a SequenceFixture call this in the fitnesse page like so

|show|fixture is of type|